Pycharm - How do you change the path to libraries? At our company we keep the libraries in Artifactory
Where I work all access to the outside world is blocked so they maintain the Python packages internally on something called Artifactory.   I'm new to Pycharm configuration and  need to know how to configure Pycharm to use the custom URL.   Any help would be gratefully appreciated.
Been snooping around all of the menus and settings and unable to locate the correct place.  I also did some googling and found a couple references that didn't match the 2023 Community version I'm using.
Been trying all of the path stuff recommended but the packages are in Artifactory which is reference with a URL.

Does this answer your question? How can I import a package from a local PyPI which requires authentication using PyCharm?

You don't reference any package in Python code with an URL anyway, you install them into your Python environment with e.g. pip (or, say, uv). If you don't specify an index to install from, pip install will default to pypi.org.
Your company's Artifactory (or its admins) should have instructions on how to use that index URL your chosen package installer, but in general, it'd be pip --index-url=https://user:password@my-company-artifactory/whatever/blah/blah or the PIP_INDEX_URL environment variable for pip.
